# Is there a tool for reformatting an XML file so that there are two attributes on a line?

Tags: xml, formatting

I have a number of XML files that are currently formatted so that all the attributes are on one very long line. I would like to reformat them automatically since doing it manually is tedious and error prone. I have found several options for reformatting them so that there is one attribute on each line. I found these options using Google. Some of them can be found via the following links.

- [Is there a stylesheet or Windows commandline tool for controllable XML formatting, specifically putting attributes one-per-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568310/is-there-a-stylesheet-or-windows-commandline-tool-for-controllable-xml-formattin)
- [How to format a XML file with long list of attributes?](https://superuser.com/questions/479833/how-to-format-a-xml-file-with-long-list-of-attributes)

The problem is that I would rather have two attributes per line. Is there a tool that supports that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Saxon serializer when run with indent=yes, will move attributes to a new line if the line would otherwise become too long. The line length can be set using the serialization option saxon:line-length and defaults to 80. (Good old punched cards!)

If you just want to format a file without any transformation, the simplest way is to run the identity query ".", like this:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:. -s:myxml.xml !indent=yes !saxon:line-length=50
```

Note that with some shell processors the "!" needs to be escaped with backslash; I don't think this applies to the DOS command line processor.

There is also an option to control order of attributes but (sorry!) no direct way of controlling the number of attributes output per line. If you fancy doing some programming, Saxon's serializer is highly customizable.

Comment: Where can I get this?

A Google search lead me to the Saxonica: XSLT and XQuery Processing library found at http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml.

Comment: You're almost there. Go back to that site and click on "products" or "evaluation copy".